# Insert form in MySQL with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In PHP 4 you would enter a form to a MySQL db like this:

```
<form  action="script.php" method="post">
 <fieldset>
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Insert your name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" />           
 </fieldset>
</form>​
```

script.php:

```
$name= $_POST['name'];  
$name = stripslashes($name);  
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "INSERT INTO names (id, name) VALUES ('','$name')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
```

Now PHP 5 is out, what is the correct notation to put this form in a MySQL db by the latest standards using PDO?

Comment: Look up the manual, attempt something. When you encounter an error, report back to SO and we will help. You will not learn if we give you the code

Comment: With minimal googling effort you can get the complete answer to your question - php.net is your ultimate resource to all php functions

Comment: @PeeHaa OP is asking for code conversion, not SQL Injection prevention

Comment: @DarylGill If you would have taken the trouble of looking at the actual answer over there you should see that it perfectly answers OP. Sure it doesn't convert 1:1 OPs code. But that's what rentacoder is for

Comment: It's questions like these that turns one against the other. (Then, we wait for the "you know what" to hit the fan).

Comment: You're looking for the [PDO tutorial for MySQL developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less the simplest way to run an update using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MyDBName",aDBUser,aDBPassword);

// Disable emulated prepared statements 
// PDO will **TRY** to use real (non-emaulated) prepared statements
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Some sample data
$aTitle = 'PHP Security';
$anAuthor = 'John Doe';

// Prepare a statement with some placeholders prefixed by ':'
$sql = "INSERT "
     . "  INTO books "
     . "       ( title, author   ) "
     . "VALUES ( :title, :author )"
     ;
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

// Execute the prepared statement and replace placeholders by values
$q->execute(array(':author' => $anAuthor,
                  ':title'  => $aTitle
                 )
           );
```

Additionally, you might wish to review [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/)'s [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Use_Prepared_Statements).

**Security consideration**

If the DB-driver isn't able to use native prepared statements, it falls back to emulated prepared statements (which might be less secure). From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php):

> **PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES** Enables or disables emulation of prepared
>   statements. Some drivers do not support native prepared statements or
>   have limited support for them. Use this setting to force PDO to either
>   always emulate prepared statements (if TRUE), or to try to use native
>   prepared statements (if FALSE). It **will always fall back to emulating**
>   the prepared statement if the **driver cannot successfully prepare** the
>   current query. Requires bool.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
$mysqlconn=  new PDO('mysql:dbname=' .$database . ';host=' . $host,  $username,  $password);
$query = "INSERT INTO names (id, name) VALUES (:id,:name)";     
$statement=$mysqlconn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(array(':id'=>null,':name'=>$name));
```

This is the core of that logic ported to PDO. You'll have to fill the missing parts.

Comment: You'll thank me for it. (edit)

Comment: Still think that self-righteousness is a disease in any community driven plattform such as S.O. But thank you, you meant well.

Comment: Some can be harder to deal with than others, I agree. However, harsh words should not be included in an answer. But I do know how you feel. Even I can be hard to deal with at times ;-)